# Preventing <span> from deletion in a contenteditable <div>

Tags: jquery, textarea, contenteditable

I am trying to make this contenteditable div behave like Twitter's text area. The goal is to be able to highlight characters entered beyond the character limit (as twitter does), which turned out impossible using a `<textarea>` as I learned that you can't select a slice of the text and format it (please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

That said, I know questions like this have been asked before but my problem, as I work toward that larger area, is very specific. I have the following code:

```
    <div id="myTextArea" class="" contenteditable="true">
        <span id="textAreaContent">enter text here...</span>
        <div id="charCountWrapper">
            <span id="charCounter"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery code to make this do what I need it to do:

```
var maxCharacters = 50;
$('#charCounter').text(maxCharacters);

$('#myTextArea').bind('input', function(){
    var charCount = $('#charCounter');
    var currentStr =  $('#textAreaContent').text();
    var newlines = $($(this).html()).length;
    var currentStrLength = currentStr.length;
    console.log(currentStr);    

    if (!!newlines) newlines -= 1;
    currentStr += newlines;

    if (currentStrLength > (maxCharacters - 11))
        charCount.addClass('over');
    else
        charCount.removeClass('over');

    charCount.text(maxCharacters - currentStrLength);

    if(currentStrLength == 0) {
        var node = document.createElement("span");          // Create a <span> node
        node.setAttribute("id","textAreaContent");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("");         // Create a text node
        node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
        document.getElementById("myTextArea").appendChild(node);
    }
});
```

When I delete the last character from the `<span>`, the tag is automatically removed and my counter stops working. I tried manually adding a new `<span>` to replace the old one, but that hasn't worked either. How can I fix this such that when I delete the last character, the count is 0, and once I start adding characters again, the counter works properly.

[image]

When I'm at the last character:

[image]

Once I delete the last character:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is actually super simple :-).

`<span>` is an `inline` element by default and has the width of its contents. When you have no content in it, the width is 0.

So just set it to `display:block;` and make the `width:100%;` to be sure.

Here is the working fiddle:

```js
var maxCharacters = 50;
$('#charCounter').text(maxCharacters);

$('#myTextArea').bind('input', function(){
    var charCount = $('#charCounter');
    var currentStr =  $('#textAreaContent').text();
    var newlines = $($(this).html()).length;
    var currentStrLength = currentStr.length;
    console.log(currentStr);    

    if (!!newlines) newlines -= 1;
    currentStr += newlines;

    if (currentStrLength > (maxCharacters - 11))
        charCount.addClass('over');
    else
        charCount.removeClass('over');

    charCount.text(maxCharacters - currentStrLength);

    /*if(currentStrLength == 0) {
        var node = document.createElement("span");          // Create a <span> node
        node.setAttribute("id","textAreaContent");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("");         // Create a text node
        node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
        document.getElementById("myTextArea").appendChild(node);
    }*/
});
```

```css
#textAreaContent{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTextArea" class="" contenteditable="true">
        <span id="textAreaContent">enter text here...</span>
        <div id="charCountWrapper">
            <span id="charCounter"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO: So your span element was never removed but had a width of 0.**

Comment: Holy Shit! I can't believe this was it. Chrome inspect mode showed me that the browser was adding a <br> after the <span> disappeared which is what threw me off in the first place, Thanks a bunch though, this saves me so much pain!!

Comment: span is actually removed when you delete the content then press backspace twice

Comment: also removed with CTRL+a+backspace or simply delete to the left